# Allow only numbers to be typed in a textbox

Tags: javascript

How to allow only numbers to be written in this textbox ?

```
<input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="extra7" name="extra7">
```

Comment: What do you class as a number? Are these numbers `12.3`, `-4`, `V`, `six`?

Comment: Not sure if a jquery question would be a duplicate. Javascript != jQuery

Comment: **This isn't an exact duplicate** of the referenced question. This targets a javascript answer while the other targets a jQuery answer. Different audiences, different solutions.

Comment: Shortest Answer is  onkeypress='return event.charCode>31 && (event.charCode <= 48 || event.charCode >= 57)'

Comment: const onlyNumbers = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const asciiCode = event.target.value.charCodeAt(0);
  (asciiCode < 48 || asciiCode > 57) ? event.target.value =  '' : event.target.value = event.target.value;
}

Answer (score 281, accepted):

You could subscribe for the onkeypress event:

```
<input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="extra7" name="extra7" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
```

and then define the `isNumber` function:

```
function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can see it in [action here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm2hS/).

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret your `if` clause. If it's larger than 57, it's always larger than 31. I think you can eliminate the parentheses.

Comment: Thank it is working. What is the chars code range for only letters? I mean I want to do it to accept letters only also in a different function of course

Comment: @Giorkouros, here's the ASCII table: http://www.asciitable.com/ Depending on what you mean by letters the result will be different. For example if you want A-Z, then the range is [65, 90], and a-z is [97, 122].

Comment: That doesn't work if you c/p some text

Comment: I can still copy and paste non numeric values in the textbox

Comment: Unfortunately there's no definitive way (short of using Flash) to prevent pasting of non numeric values. That's why it's always important to validate form input on submit.

Comment: Works. Can someone pls tell me how to get the final value in the textbox once this validated?

Comment: It works. Copy and paste is allowed only if we paste via mouse (on right button of mouse). If we use Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V to input then this code works great and not allow paste texts. +1 and thanks

Comment: This is the definitive way to solve this issue once and for all: https://gist.github.com/nbouvrette/84ef4f498ac06cdd5b60

Comment: I tried this, it works perfectly on Chrome and IE but not on Firefox. In firefox, pressing the delete key will not delete. It will not do anything. Anyone faces this issue?

Comment: Accepted solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168918/html-keycodes-not-working-in-firefox , works in all browsers

Comment: Doesn't work on mobile (Android + Chrome)

Comment: Just accepting numeric values from the alphabetic part of keyboard. Why this function is not accepting numeric keypad keys situated on the right side of keyboard?

Comment: Not working property as no. can be negative also

Comment: as November 2017, this is throwing an error in chrome "Uncaught ReferenceError: evt is not defined". The first line should be: var evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;

Comment: To include the numpad characters: `if ((charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) || ((charCode >= 96 && charCode <= 105))) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;`

Comment: @Milana this makes impossible to select all text, use tab or left right,  backspace and copy/paste text.

Comment: Not working properly! It accepts special characters like !"#$%&/ etc.

Comment: this is not working when i open page in mobile browser

Comment: @DarinDimitrov This code works absolutely fine, but I have a text-box field which represents "Discount" for the product and that discount can be in decimal. How could we allow Dot(.) to be be able to put into textbox? Appreciate your help

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31169709/4093658

Comment: What happens if input occurs from a non-keypress? For example, an external source manipulating an input field.

Answer (score 50):

With HTML5 you can do

```
<input type="number">
```

You can also use a regex pattern to limit the input text.

```
<input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]*$" />
```

Comment: This does not prevent non-numeric characters from being entered.

Comment: @MyNameIsKo it should, maybe you are using a client that does not support this kind of HTML5 feature?

Comment: it does not work in either Chrome or Firefox. You may be referring to submission validation of non-numeric characters, which does work properly with HTML5. The original question, however, was interested in preventing the non-numeric entry entirely. I'm pretty sure JavaScript is still the only way to do this.

Comment: I see, but what does "entry" mean? One can not prevent what a user types on his keyboard while this element is active...

Comment: By entry, I mean character input into a textbox. Using JavaScript, you absolutely can prevent a user from entering certain characters, just look at the accepted answer. Obviously, user's can still break this, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: @powtac yes you can... have you ever used Angular or any other JS frameworks?

Comment: Allows "." , which may not be desirable

Comment: input type number and pattern both allowing alphabets to enter in field in my browser i.e chrome

Comment: The type number is not supporting on Firefox.

Answer (score 16):

You also can use some HTML5 attributes, some browsers might already take advantage of them (`type="number" min="0"`).

Whatever you do, remember to re-check your inputs on the server side: you can never assume the client-side validation has been performed.

Comment: The type number and min are not supporting on Firefox