# How to set NumberTextBox accepts only digits in dojo?

Tags: dojo, validation

I have the following `NumberTextBox` and i wanted to allow only the digits,but i don't know what is the `constraints` properties used to make it possible.

```
<input type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.NumberTextBox" invalidMessage="Please enter only numbers" constraints="{}" required="true"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have following for example:

```
constraints: { min:0, places:0}
```

see also: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Number_Format_Patterns

Using the dojo NumberTextBox you are still allowed to enter characters: a, b, c. It only gives you invalid message. If you want to only allow digit input, you can use the javascript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295843/allow-only-numbers-to-be-typed-in-a-textbox).

Comment: Thanks for you help.But I also want to get rid of the negative sign and fraction value.I want to allow only numbers from 0-9.

Comment: @VijinPaulraj, try the edited answer. Your question was somewhat misleading with use of 'decimal' word.

Comment: Sorry for that..Anyway that works fine.How to customize the "out of range" alert to "please enter positive nos"!!

Comment: you may also want to specify a pattern of "###" to avoid thousands separators.