# Disable Text Entry in <input type="number">

Tags: html, validation, user-input

I am making a simple web app. At one part of it, I have included an input box of type="number"

```
<input type="number" min="0">
```

Anyhow, when I run the code in my latest Google Chrome Browser, I am able to enter text too:

[image: I entered text in an input type of number]

I do not want users to be able to do that. How should I rectify this?

Comment: add javascript to catch input and delete anything that's not a number.

Comment: @MarcB How do I do that?

Comment: Try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295843/allow-only-numbers-to-be-typed-in-a-textbox

Comment: Note: You could also use the `pattern` attribute. 

http://html5pattern.com/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use JavaScript (e.g. with jQuery) to allow only specific characters:

```
// Catch all events related to changes
$('#textbox').on('change keyup', function() {
  // Remove invalid characters
  var sanitized = $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  // Update value
  $(this).val(sanitized);
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pj5cU/) is a fiddle.

Same thing with support for floats:

```
// Catch all events related to changes
$('#textbox').on('change keyup', function() {
  // Remove invalid characters
  var sanitized = $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
  // Remove the first point if there is more than one
  sanitized = sanitized.replace(/\.(?=.*\.)/, '');
  // Update value
  $(this).val(sanitized);
});
```

And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pj5cU/1/) is another fiddle.

**Update:** Although you might not need this, here is a solution that allows a leading minus sign.

```
// Catch all events related to changes
$('#textbox').on('change keyup', function() {
  // Remove invalid characters
  var sanitized = $(this).val().replace(/[^-0-9]/g, '');
  // Remove non-leading minus signs
  sanitized = sanitized.replace(/(.)-+/g, '$1');
  // Update value
  $(this).val(sanitized);
});
```

[3rd fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pj5cU/2/)

And now a final solution that allows only **valid** decimals (including floats and negative numbers):

```
// Catch all events related to changes
$('#textbox').on('change keyup', function() {
  // Remove invalid characters
  var sanitized = $(this).val().replace(/[^-.0-9]/g, '');
  // Remove non-leading minus signs
  sanitized = sanitized.replace(/(.)-+/g, '$1');
  // Remove the first point if there is more than one
  sanitized = sanitized.replace(/\.(?=.*\.)/g, '');
  // Update value
  $(this).val(sanitized);
});
```

[Final fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pj5cU/3/)

Comment: this don't work for me because even there is char on input, the  $(this).val() equals ''

Comment: how could you move the input cursor to the same place as before? you can write in the middle as well

Answer (score 4):

You can use [HTML5 input type number](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html) to restrict only number entries:

```
<input type="number" name="someid" />
```

This will work only in HTML5 complaint browser. Make sure your html document's doctype is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

For general purpose, you can have JS validation as below:

```
function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}

<input type="someid" name="number" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"/>
```

If you want to allow decimals replace the "if condition" with this:

```
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode != 46 &&(charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)))
```

Source: [HTML Text Input allow only Numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input)

Comment: I like your solution but the decimal validation is incorrect. `1.2.3.4` is obviously not a valid decimal. BTW, your code snippet also prevents keyboard shortcuts such as `CTRL+A` and `CTRL+C` from working.

Comment: @still_learning `CTRL+A` and `CTRL+C` is working fine.. and `1.2.3.4` is not a valid decimal.. correct.. but i believe we haven't written this code to valid decimal numbers... the requirement is different....

Answer (score 0):

Just add onkeydown="return false".

```html
<input type="number" min="0" onkeydown="return false">
```