# How to disable input on type="number" but only keep spinners usable

Tags: css, html, input

So I need to disable input on:

`<input type="number" name="name" value="0" min="0" max="1" />`

But keep the spinners working... to avoid some input anything above or beneath min and max.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Text Entry in <input type="number">](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215049/disable-text-entry-in-input-type-number)

Comment: It's different because I need solution which disables input completely but leaves rollers working, so nobody can input anything but only use rollers for input...

Comment: `Number` input type isn't supported in IE by the way.

Comment: I really don't care for IE, all my web sites offer downloading Firefox or Chrome to capture full user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[jquery](http://jquery.com/download/)** for this task:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9vr57wwL/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" name="name" value="0" min="0" max="1" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT (JQUERY)**

```
$('input[type="number"]').keydown(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Nice solution. You don't necessarily need JQuery though, if you give it an ID you can use the `onkeydown` event. EG: `document.getElementById("myNumericInput").onkeydown=function(e){e.preventDefault();}`

Comment: Not necessarily, how will you solve multiple input type numbers? You would have to create the event per `id`. You can use `document.querySelectorAll`, however that doesn't work on some browser versions.

Comment: Just give them all a class (most likely already will have a shared class) and iterate over `document.getElementsByClassName`?

Comment: As mentioned, such would not work on some browser versions, particularly IE

Comment: Oh right, particularly IE < 9 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName