# Jquery discount calculation from range

Tags: javascript, jquery, range, price, discount

I have a product, its price is $ 10. The price is $ 9 if the customer buys 11 of this product, and $ 8 if he buys 21. iki tane array var whole_sell_qty ve whole_sell_price.
How should I develop an algorithm, when the amount of the product is 11, multiply the price by $ 9 and print it in the total area.

```js
var whole_sell_qty = [10, 20, 30];
var whole_sell_price = [10, 9, 8];
$(".quantity").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
   $("#total").text($("#price").val() * $(".quantity").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
table, th, td, tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>

<label>Product name : shoe</label><br>

<label>Product price : </label><input type="number" id="price" value="10" disabled><span>$</span><br>

<label>Qty : </label> <input type="number" name="quantity" class="quantity" value="1"/><br>

<label>Total : <span id="total"></span></label>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>qty range</th>
<th>unit price</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1-10</td>
<td>$ 10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11-20</td>
<td>$ 9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>21-30</td>
<td>$ 8</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: `.bind()` has been deprecated for years, you should use `.on()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example (elements of `whole_sell_qty` are sorted and values are evenly spaced out) you can get the index of the element in `whole_sell_price` like this:

```
let qty = $(".quantity").val();
let index = Math.floor( (qty-1)/10 );
if(index < 0) {
    index = 0;
} else if(index > whole_sell_qty.length-1) {
    index = whole_sell_qty.length - 1;
}
```

If the elements in `whole_sell_qty` were not spaced out evenly then you could make a function to figure out the correct price for the given quantity:

```
function setPrice() {
    let qty = $(".quantity").val();
    let length = whole_sell_qty.length;
    
    for(let i=0; i < length; i++) {
        if(qty > whole_sell_qty[i])
            continue;
    
        $("#total").text(qty * whole_sell_price[i]);
        return;
    }
    $("#total").text(qty * whole_sell_price[length-1]);
}
```

**Note:** Both of these solutions assume your two arrays `whole_sell_qty` and `whole_sell_price` have matching elements in the same indexes. If that is not the case you could consider using an object to represent the different quantities and their respective prices.

---

**Try it out:**

Note: I added the `min` attribute to the `input[type="number"]` element so you can't click your way to a value less than 0. But you can still enter a negative number manually in the text field. For that I didn't provide a solution here but you can see how to deal with that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215049/disable-text-entry-in-input-type-number).

```js
var whole_sell_qty = [10, 20, 30];
var whole_sell_price = [10, 9, 8];

$(".quantity").on('click', function () {
    let qty = $(".quantity").val();
    // this will get the correct price index for whole_sell_price based on qty
    let index = Math.floor( (qty-1)/10 );

    if(index < 0) {
        index = 0;
    } else if(index > whole_sell_qty.length-1) {
        index = whole_sell_qty.length - 1;
    }
    
    $("#total").text(qty * whole_sell_price[index]);
});
```

```css
table, th, td, tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Product name : shoe</label><br>
<label>Product price : </label><input type="number" id="price" value="10" disabled><span>$</span><br>
<label>Qty : </label> <input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" class="quantity" value="0"/><br>
<label>Total : <span id="total">0</span></label>

<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>qty range</th>
    <th>unit price</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1-10</td>
    <td>$ 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11-20</td>
    <td>$ 9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21-30</td>
    <td>$ 8</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var whole_sell_qty = [10, 20, 30];
var whole_sell_price = [10, 9, 8];
$(".quantity").on('change', function () {
   var sell_value = get_round_up_ten($(this).val());
  var sell_key = whole_sell_qty.indexOf(sell_value);
  console.log("sell price: " + whole_sell_price[sell_key]);
});

var get_round_up_ten = function(val) {
  return Math.ceil(val / 10) * 10;
}
```