# Bootstrap vue input type="number"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

When creating type="number" input, it getting  '+' or '-' characters. I want to prevent it. However when I tried to watch every state changed on input value, it does not show '+' or '-' characters.

input:

```
  <b-form-input   
      v-model="port"
      type="number"             
     >
```

and watch:

```
watch: {
    port(val){
      console.log("val ", val)
    }
  },
```

For example when I write '564+-' to the input then the watch just can follow '564'. How can prevent minus and plus characters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Text Entry in <input type="number">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215049/disable-text-entry-in-input-type-number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by cancel the keyboard event for invalid input using `keydown` event.

**Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    port: "",
  },
  methods: {
    portKeydown(e) {
      if (/^\+$/.test(e.key)) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="demo">
    <div>
      <div>With key handler:</div>
      <input type="number" v-model="port" @keydown="portKeydown($event)" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```