# Javascript Textbox Values output NAN on.Change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am really really new to javascript and tried googling. but I don't find any luck.
So please help me, everytime i input a value into a textbox. the other textbox's will show "nan" then when I tried to change the NaN Value, the first textbox that I typed in to will return the first thousand digits of the value.

here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zzxwV/5/) of my proble

and these are my codes

```
$(document).on('change', '#family_home,#home_contents,#motor_vehicle,#Total', function() {
updateTotal();
    });       
var updateTotal =function() {
var a = parseInt($('#family_home').val());
$('#family_home').val(a.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
var b = parseInt($('#home_contents').val());
$('#home_contents').val(b.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
var c = parseInt($('#motor_vehicle').val());
$('#motor_vehicle').val(c.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
var total = parseInt(a)+parseInt(b)+parseInt(c);   
$("#Total").html(total);         
};
```

Please Please help. Thanks. I know im a newbie but I want to gain more knowledge from you guys. so please pass it on to me. Thanks

Comment: Duplicates -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295843/allow-only-numbers-to-be-typed-in-a-textbox, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
$(document).on('change', '#family_home,#home_contents,#motor_vehicle,#Total', function() {
    updateTotal();
    });       
    var updateTotal =function() {
    var re=new RegExp(",","g");
    var a = parseInt($('#family_home').val().replace(re,""),10);
    if(!isNaN(a))
    $('#family_home').val(a.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
    var b = parseInt($('#home_contents').val().replace(re,""),10);
    if (!isNaN(b))
    $('#home_contents').val(b.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
    var c = parseInt($('#motor_vehicle').val().replace(re,""),10);
    if (!isNaN(c))
    $('#motor_vehicle').val(c.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
    var total = parseInt(a)+parseInt(b)+parseInt(c);   
    $("#Total").html(total);         
};
```

Comment: wow thanks, this totally works. but how can I set each textbox to automatically output the comma's when i clicked on the next texbox? I tried .on('keyup') but it returns the whole number to the first thousands.

Comment: For output commas, you will have use your current logic for string replace. but be careful, while reading the values and passing them to parseInt make sure that you again replace the commas with empty string i.e. "" so that parseInt parses the inputs correctly.

Also while using parseInt always include a second argument i.e.
parseInt(mytext,10);   the second argument 10 ensures that you want the parsed value to be in decimal (10) system. other possibilities are 2 (binary), 16 (hexadecimal), 8 (octal).

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code above to reflect what you want. Could not save the fiddle due to some error.

Comment: Why -1 to my answer ? Please specify the reason.

Comment: This really is awesome, Thank you for you help. I wish I could vote for your answer. This really helped me. THanks so much

Comment: Oh, I am new to Stackexchange, I was not aware that there is a chat feature available. I will check it out next time !! thanks for notifying.

Answer (score 0):

[NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) property is a value that represents "Not-a-number". To avoid this behavior in your code, you might use the `isNaN()` function:

```
$(document).on('change', '#family_home,#home_contents,#motor_vehicle,#Total', function() {
    updateTotal();
    });       
var updateTotal =function() {
var a = parseInt($('#family_home').val());
    $('#family_home').val(a.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
var b = parseInt($('#home_contents').val());
    if (!isNaN(b))
    $('#home_contents').val(b.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
var c = parseInt($('#motor_vehicle').val());
    if (!isNaN(c))
    $('#motor_vehicle').val(c.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
var total = parseInt(a)+parseInt(b)+parseInt(c);   
    $("#Total").html(total);         
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/zzxwV/6/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN