# Prevent the insertion of text

Tags: javascript

I have an input

```
type = number
```

How can I prevent the user to enter the text within?  I must reading only numbers.

```
<input type = "number" id = "case">
```

Comment: A possible solution, go here: http://www.qodo.co.uk/blog/javascript-restrict-keyboard-character-input/

Comment: Will this work?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295843/allow-only-numbers-to-be-typed-in-a-textbox

Comment: @OP, if your issue solved, either close this thread or answer your question.