# can't validate on mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, firefox

I'm doing, what everybody does on the forums, but something goes wrong, I can't validate my forms on mozilla firefox with my initial code, it runs well on any browser but not on mozilla, the initial code was:

```
function ValidateOnlyText() {
 if ((event.keyCode != 32) && (event.keyCode < 65) 
    || (event.keyCode > 90) && (event.keyCode < 97) 
    || (event.keyCode > 122))
    {alert("only text");
  event.returnValue = false;
}
```

That function is executed, everytime the user writes something on an input with, onkeypress, an example:

```
<input class="inputShort" name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" onkeypress="ValidateOnlyText()"/>
```

So, searching and searching, I found it a lot of people that corrects that issue on firefox, and I test it, keyCode for the other browsers, and which for firefox, I do that on the javascript code:

```
function ValidaSoloTextos(e) {
    var key=document.all?e.keyCode:e.which;
    if ((key!=32)&&(key<65)||(key>90)&&(key<97)||(key>122)){
        alert("solo texto");
        return false;
    }
}
```

and add on the input this:

```
onkeypress="ValidaSoloTextos(this.value)"
```

What is wrong on that? I'm going to search more, and if I find something I update the post, thanks all

Comment: I'm just thinking about that, that's not this.value, it's 'e' I thougt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an event to your function:

```
<input class="inputShort" name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" onkeypress="ValidateOnlyText(event)"/>
```

So change `this.value` to `event`

Also I would change `document.all` to `e.keyCode`, makes more sense.

Add `return` before `ValidateOnlyText(event)` to stop unwanted characters from being typed in.

This might also be of any use to you:
[Allow only numbers to be typed in a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295843/allow-only-numbers-to-be-typed-in-a-textbox)

Comment: ok, I changed it but, mozilla still failing, on the other browsers goes well