# How to restrict input only as numbers in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to input only numbers while entering and restrict characters.

```
{!! Form::input('text','advertisement_height',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: Did you bother to research how to do this first…? Laravel has numeric validation, and there’ll be hundreds of JavaScript libraries that restrict input to numbers only.

Comment: Check the answer posted here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input

Answer (score 1):

You could change the input type to a number field.

```
<input type="number" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The Laravel validation class comes with a bunch of different number validators: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#available-validation-rules

You can see there is **integer** and **numeric**. If you have the request in your control you could just write the rules for it.

```
// on your controller
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $rules = ['advertisement_height' => 'required|numeric'];
  $this->validate($request, $rules);
}
```

or you can create a validation object and run the validation on your input, however you get it.

Answer (score 1):

Try it here!

```
<input id="txtnum" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" type="text" name="txtnum">
```

Note that digits are allowed and alphabetic characters are not allowed. Observe, too, that arrow keys and backspace are allowed so that you can still edit what you type.

```
function isNumber(evt)
  {
     var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
     if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

     return true;
  }
```

Possible Answer: [Allow only numbers to be typed in a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295843/allow-only-numbers-to-be-typed-in-a-textbox)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lm2hS/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "text" say "number":

```
Form::input('number'....
```

I think `Form::number()...` doesn't exist any more

Answer (score 0):

{{Form::number('name','default_text',array('class' => 'form-control', 'required'))}}

use 'number' instead of 'text' and 'required' attribute for mandatory field.