# Validation for textfield to restrict for 6 digits

Tags: javascript, magento

we need to set validation in textfield : "zip code" under checkout process in magento site.

i need to restrict this textfield for maximum 6 digits.

i am using following code for this :

```
    <input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?>"
 name="billing[postcode]" id="billing:postcode" 
 value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getPostcode()) ?>"
 class="input-text validate-zip-international
 <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>" placeholder="Postal code"/>
```

please help me to give validation for **Restricting only for 6 digits**

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295843/allow-only-numbers-to-be-typed-in-a-textbox

Comment: That combined with the `maxlength` attribute should do you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 function limit(element)
    {
        var max_chars = 6;

        if(element.value.length > max_chars) {
            element.value = element.value.substr(0, max_chars);
        }
    }

 <input type="text" onkeydown="limit(this);" onkeyup="limit(this); "title="<?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?>"
 name="billing[postcode]" id="billing:postcode" 
 value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getPostcode()) ?>"
 class="input-text validate-zip-international
 <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>" placeholder="Postal code"/>
```

Comment: now its displaying like this : http://prntscr.com/a1r0e8 i you can see increment button at the end ,  i want to remove those. and after i entered 6 digits, if i enter one more digit its increasing the last digit.

Comment: means 110001 i entered, than if i enter another number its increasing as 110002......

Comment: try <input type="text" onkeydown="limit(this);" onkeyup="limit(this);" > it worked for me, are you sure there isn't anything else in the code that is causing this?

Answer (score 2):

The better way is use [the pattern attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp):

```
<input type="number" maxlength="6" pattern="[0-9]{6,}" placeholder="Zip code" required>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example for validating phone number of 10 digits:

Html :

`<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" onkeypress="phoneno()" maxlength="10">`

Script file:

```
<script>        
       function phoneno(){          
        $('#phone').keypress(function(e) {
            var a = [];
            var k = e.which;

            for (i = 48; i < 58; i++)
                a.push(i);

            if (!(a.indexOf(k)>=0))
                e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
   </script>
```

Comment: can you please update the code with my code for zip code restriction for 6 digits