# jquery input masked digits

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input field form to enter credit card number and I want to enter first 4 and last 4 digits how can I do it?

For example: In image when I focus and fill input it must fill group 1 and group 2 characters

[click see to demo](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/NAOxXy)

[image]

My HTML

```
<input type="text" name="kredi_karti" id="kredi_karti" class="form-control kredi_karti">
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).on("focus",".kredi_karti",function(){
    $(this).mask("9999 9999 9999 9999",{placeholder:"XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX"});
});
```

Comment: no my question is not about it..if I fill form it must pass second and third area which I mark or if I fill form it must just fill first and last area

Comment: $(this).mask("9999 XXXX XXXX 9999",{placeholder:"XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX"}); ?

Comment: it's a plugin jquery input masked plugin

Comment: yep, I know. So, 9 - is any number, and all other symbols - placeholder

Comment: this just for credit card number and I don't know how can I make that I want

Answer (score 1):

that's not so hard as you think, you can write  a key down event function and store the key input in the variable and return the mask keycode to set in input, you also have to verify the key code if its delete or backspace you have to change the stored card number accordingly

here is the code which allows only numbers .. you have to extend the functionality

[Allow only numbers to be typed in a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295843/allow-only-numbers-to-be-typed-in-a-textbox)

Answer (score 1):

Try this out to skip the second and third groups of numbers

```
$(this).mask('0000.XXXX.XXXX.0000', {
  translation: {
    'X': {
      pattern: /X/,
      fallback: 'X'
    }
  },
  placeholder: "____.XXXX.XXXX.____"
});
```

Comment: hi I tried and it didn't work as you can see: http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/NAOxXy

Comment: Oops, didnt notice the plugin of your choice. My snippet works with this one http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js to achieve the behavior.