# jQuery - How can I allow both numpad and number key row input; as well as prevent special characters from being entered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to allow both number pad numeric and oridinary number from keyboard. Currently, it only allows the number key row. I also only want numbers to be entered, but it currently allows special characters.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#price').keydown(function(event) {
        if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) && event.which != 8) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='price'>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow only numbers to be typed in a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295843/allow-only-numbers-to-be-typed-in-a-textbox)

Comment: `<input type='number'>`

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this [plug-in (Fork of texotela's numeric jquery plugin). This (jStepper)](https://github.com/cstaylor/numeric.js/tree/master) is another one.

This is a [link](https://github.com/nicksergeant/snipt) if you want to build it yourself.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txtboxToFilter").keydown(function (e) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
             // Allow: Ctrl+A, Command+A
            (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

NOTE: If your webpage uses HTML5, you can use the built-in `<input type="number">` and use the min and max properties to control the minimum and maximum value.

```
$(function() {
  $('#staticParent').on('keydown', '#child', function(e){-1!==$.inArray(e.keyCode,[46,8,9,27,13,110,190])||(/65|67|86|88/.test(e.keyCode)&&(e.ctrlKey===true||e.metaKey===true))&&(!0===e.ctrlKey||!0===e.metaKey)||35<=e.keyCode&&40>=e.keyCode||(e.shiftKey||48>e.keyCode||57<e.keyCode)&&(96>e.keyCode||105<e.keyCode)&&e.preventDefault()});
})

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="staticParent">
    <input id="child" type="textarea" />
</div>
```

I coppied from it on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)

If its help for you.Please  vote first writer .

Comment: a complete answer for control only numeric values ; tnax

Answer (score 1):

Updated your code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#price').keydown(function(event) {
        if((event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57) && event.shiftKey) {
            event.preventDefault();    
        }
        if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) && event.which != 8) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use keypress for that instead of keydown

then

the keyCode of `0` to `9` are `48` to `57` so use this condition

```
if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
   event.preventDefault(); 
}
```

this condition returns true if you enter keys that are not 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8 and 9 or not numbers

So your code would be like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#price').keypress(function(event) {
       if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
           event.preventDefault(); 
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='price'>
```

Comment: It allow special characters now

Comment: I tested it and it doesn't allowed special chars , it only allows number

Answer (score 0):

Why we don't user input type number. I think just do it easy like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='number' id='price'>
```