# How to allow only numbers in textbox

Tags: javascript

```
    function AllowOnlyNumbers(evt) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)){
            if (charCode === 8 && charCode === 46) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

How to allow only numbers and `delete key` or `backspace` to be written in this textbox ?

Comment: Why not make it an input of type "number"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML text input allows only numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allows-only-numeric-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use input of type number `<input type="number" />` for browsers that supports it, otherwise use javascript:

```
function AllowOnlyNumbers(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lm2hS/

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7295864/235659

Comment: Thanks for answer, I used `<input type="number" />` It not wored

Comment: I added a fiddle, it works fine, but this depends on your browser, I just tried in Chrome, it works fine but doesn't work in Safari for example. So it depends on what browsers you're targetting.

Comment: I use firefox and what is fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for answer, only `del` key not worked. but `backspace` key worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have created this solution for your problem here:

https://codebrace.com/editor/b05f92054

Here I have used

```
event.charCode == 0
```

to allow non characters key pressed (To allow delete, backspace and other non-character keys) and

```
isNaN
```

to check if the value entered is a number or not.
I hope this helps!